# Eclipse code tooltips for PHP development (Complete function reference)

Tags: php, eclipse, function, tooltip

When programming PHP in Eclipse *some* PHP function will show up -- while many functions are mssing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1w7.gif

How do I get the missing functions (like *round* or *rand* for r... / *`str_replace`* for s... etc.pp.) to show up in this list?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=171010&#page_top

Appearently, reinstalling to the newest version fixes this!